# Replacing Values in a List Column Not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[(UUID('123'),), (UUID('456'),),...(UUID('789'),)]
```

I want to format it so that it looks like this

```
['123','456','789']
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
for x in range(0,len(my_list),1):

my_list[x] = my_list[x].replace('(UUID(','')
my_list[x] = my_list[x].replace('),)','')
```

but I keep getting an error message:

> Could not locate column in row for column replace

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You actually have _a list of tuples of function calls and `None`_? Your `'` don't seem to match either. Please edit the code sample and clarify.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles - as the other comment says - you have list of tuples where a tuple holds a call to function. Is that correct?

Comment: Those results come out of a table from a database exactly like that. I didn't do anything to them. Does that help?

Comment: I really don't mean to be pedantic, but I don't follow: `(UUID('123'),), (UUID('456'),')` those are presumably two of the same kind of thing, but they're different. One has a single `'` as the second item in the tuple, one has nothing. If it comes out of a database, is `UUID('123')` a string, so actually `"UUID('123')"`?

Comment: I edited my post, missed the extra quote. Sorryabout that.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the entries are **strings** ... (not sure about that)

```
import re
data = ["(UUID('123'),)", "(UUID('456'),)","(UUID('789'),)"]
numbers = [int(re.findall(r'\d+',x)[0]) for x in data]
print(numbers)
```

output
[123, 456, 789]

Comment: I thought they were strings, that's how they came back from the database, but I got an error message: "expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Question. Does the answer work for you?